# Why svn log give different results in different subdirectories

Tags: svn

I've recently started working with svn previously working with git and one thing is not clear for me.

After downloading some open source project's repo let say I have given directories structure:

OpenSourceProject

- Dir1
- - Dir1.1
- - Dir1.2
- Dir2
- Dir3

When I'm in root directory (that is ls gives Dir1 Dir2 Dir3) svn log present me different values then when I'm e.g. in Dir1 (ls gives Dir1.1 Dir1.2).

In git no matter where inside I am git log will always give me same result.

Of course, I'm always on the same branch.

svn log doc says:

> The default target is the path of your current directory. If no
>   arguments are supplied, svn log shows the log messages for all files
>   and directories inside of (and including) the current working
>   directory of your working copy.

So is working directory the physical location in files tree, or working directory is branch, or how it works with svn log? Why am I seeing different logs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, svn log works different as git log, and you have properly described the behaviour. In svn, you get only the log of the current folder, whereas in git you get the log of the whole repository unless you specify a file or a folder.

As a personal note, I was surprised of this different behaviour but the other way around, since I learned svn before git.